# Magento 2 - get categories by using interfaces in API

Tags: magento-2.1, category, api, category-listing

In Magento 2, you're supposed to use the interfaces in Magento's API. So, when you want to fetch product(s), you'd use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`. That works great and it's very convenient.

Now when I want to get a list of categories, based on my search criteria. What's the best way to approach this? I don't really see the options, because:

- `\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface` only supports a single entity, no `getList()` or something like that.
- `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection\Factory` is used a lot from what I've seen from community code. However, this class is deprecated, which clearly means it shouldn't be used.
- `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory` is also used a lot. It's a dynamically generated factory. Developers would use this factory to create a category model and get it's collection. That seems really awful to me, but it's a way to go I guess..

Comment: Have you tried Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface->getTree()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About a year later, Magento naturally has evolved and the `Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryListInterface` can now be used.

It works great, I can do stuff like this:

```
/**
 * @var CategoryListInterface
 */
private $categoryListRepository;

/**
 * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
 */
private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

/**
 * CategoryList constructor.
 * @param CategoryListInterface $categoryList
 * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariableNames)
 */
public function __construct(
    CategoryListInterface $categoryListRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
) {
    $this->categoryListRepository = $categoryListRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}

/**
 * @param int $parentId
 * @return CategoryInterface[]
 */
public function getCategories(int $parentId): array
{
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('parent_id', $parentId);
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

    $results = $this->categoryListRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    return $results->getItems();
}
```

**mpw's** answer is useful as well and is supported by Magento, but my question was aiming for a service contract method.

Comment: Creating filters for for SearchCriteriaBuilder https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html

Comment: I can't tell if you are being ironic or no over this text "About a year later, Magento naturally has evolved and the Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryListInterface can now be used." Nonetheless, i just found that class so looks like it is the one to go if you want to get categories

Answer (score 1):

Since `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection` has an `@api` annotation (as of 2.2), it appears that Magento has officially sanctioned the old style.

Rather than use the deprecated `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection\Factory`, I believe Magento would prefer usage of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory`, which is generated and has no deprecation.